# mongoose, command insert is unsupported

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I connected to mongodb, and created schema. And when I try use create function I have that error:

```
    MongoServerError: command insert is unsupported, correlationID = 1778d2f5730b2f9c8356f929,
{
  ok: 0,
  code: 115,
  codeName: 'CommandNotSupported',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}

}
```

api.controller.js:

```
const Task = require('../models/Task')

const createTasks = async (req, res) => {
        const task = new Task({name: 'test', completed: false})
        await task.save()
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }
```

In app.js I have this function to start server and connect to db:

```
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB(process.env.DB_CONNETC_URL)
        log('Connected', "green", 'db')

        app.listen(port, () => log(`Listening at port ${port}`, 'green', 'connect(app.js)'))
    } catch (err) {
        log(`Error ${err}`, "red", 'db')
    }

}
```

I try reconnect to db but it's doesn't help

Comment: What is the associated code that you are using? What version of MongoDB, Mongoose, and driver are configured?

Comment: @user20042973 I use last version of the MongoDB and Mongoose

Comment: @user2004297 associated code: const task = await Task.create({name: 'test'})